# 'dynamics' or 'dynamism'

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I was describing a system where two opposing forces (not necessarily physical or chemical) have an interesting relationship to each other - in particular how a change in one affects the other etc.

I said that "there's an interesting *dynamism* going on"

However should I have used the word *dynamics* instead?

Comment: The terms have a nuanced difference. You’ll need to decide which aspect of the “interesting relationship” you meant.

Comment: Would you please provide us the dictionary definitions of these two words that you've looked up? (That way we won't have to duplicate your effort.)

Comment: If you can quantify the forces and their opposition over time variables, you could call it _dynamics_ with a clear conscience. It's part of [_statics and dynamics_](https://www.google.com/search?q=statics+and+dynamics), one of the classic basic topics in physics.